# loop python with json Dump1090

Tags: python

I will need a little advice for a personal project.
I am new to the python language. I've been looking for a solution for two days now and I'm starting to pull my hair ^^

I have a loop with two If, I don't know if this is the right solution

I would like in the first case if no plane is detected the loop starts again after 5 seconds.

In the second case if one or more planes is detected, I will want the rapart loop 10 min later to find if there are new planes or not.

Thanks in advance to all!

```
import urllib.request, json
import telepot
from time import sleep
import time

TOKEN = '1401649465:AAEMyJ87FilPAk-dbQYa7ovx4fxn5uJ1K-w'
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
    

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://localiP/data/aircraft.json") as url:
    aircraft_json = json.loads(url.read().decode())   


for dat in aircraft_json['aircraft']:
        

        try:
            altitude = dat["alt_geom"] * 0.3048
        except:
            altitude = 0
        try: 
            flight = dat["flight"]
        except:
            flight = 0
        try:
            squawk = dat["squawk"]
        except:
            squawk = 0
        try:
            speed = dat["mach"] * 1234.8
        except:
            speed = 0
        try: 
            emergency = dat["emergency"]
            if emergency == "0":
                emergency = 0
        except:
            emergency = 0
        try:
            lat = dat["lat"]
            long = dat["lon"]
        except:
            lat = 0
            long = 0

        try:
            hex = 0 #sometimes the data comes back empty, so if it fails, we will insert "0"
        except:
            hex = dat["hex"]
        

        finally:

            if None in aircraft_json['aircraft']:
                    print("No Plane!")

                    time.sleep(5)
                    


            if dat in aircraft_json['aircraft']:
                print("Vol:", flight, "Alt:", (round(altitude, 2)),"m", "Vitesse:", (round(speed, 2)), "Km/h")

                time.sleep(60*10)
```

Comment: You can get rid of all those `try: except:` by `flight = dat.get("flight", 0)` for example. [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

Comment: You should check out ```requests``` it is much simpler to use. ```response = requests.get(url)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you rearrange your code to something like this:

```
while(True):
    #...
    aircraft_json= json.loads(url.read().decode()) 

    if None in aircraft_json['aircraft']:
        print("No Plane!")
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        #parse aircraft_json['aircraft']
        #print data...
        #Do Something
        time.sleep(10*60)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Nidal , it allowed me to modify a few things in my code to start. I still have a lot of changes to make :)